# Работа со списком контактов в Андроид.

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, не подскажите как получить номер телефона из списка контактов зная имя контакта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Основы Contacts API в Android](http://habrahabr.ru/post/130148/)